# Silex bilingual URLs routing

Tags: localization, url-routing, silex

I want to know what is the best way to implement what want (see below) in Silex.

Here is what I want:

- all URLs must start with locale (/en/page1, /fr/page1, /en/page2, /fr/page2, ....)
- when the user hits the home page I will check the browser language and add /en or /fr to home page
- when adding /en or /fr to home page, is there a way to do that in Silex without redirecting (I think redirecting home page is not a good SEO practice (my knowledge in SEO is very limited so maybe i am wrong))?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/organizing_controllers.html

Especially :

```
$app->mount('/blog', $blog);
```

So using this I think you can do something like :

```
$app->mount('/{_locale}', $site);
```

I haven't tried it but I think it would work, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

To me, this was the simplest and cleanest option for Silex v2.x:

**Install the silex-local package**

`composer require pmaxs/silex-locale "^2.0"`

Add the LocalServiceProvidet to your app.php file:

```
$app->register(new Pmaxs\Silex\Locale\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider(), [
    'locale.locales' => ['en', 'ca', 'es'],
    'locale.default_locale' => 'en',
    'locale.resolve_by_host' => false,
    'locale.exclude_routes' => ['^_'],
]);

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider(), []);
```

This way, you won't have to add anything extra in your endpoints, plus everything is handled by default.

Look at https://github.com/pmaxs/silex-locale for information with Silex v1.x.